# uploading multiple files using formData

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I'm currently trying to upload multiple files using formData to my server but this one receive nothing. Here is my javascript code (property_picture is my input file)

```
FileList = [];

$("#property_picture").on('change',function (event) {
    var files = event.originalEvent.target.files;
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        FileList.push(files[i]);
    }
    console.log(FileList);


    $("#FormInfoDetailed").on('submit',function (e) {
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        for (var i = 0, len = FileList.length; i < len; i++) {

            formData.append("files", FileList[i]);
        }

        console.log(formData.get('files'));

        $.ajax({
            url: $('#FormInfoDetailed').attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
               // files1Uploader.clear();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("ERROR - " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

})
```

And here is my server code in php laravel :

```
        $file = $request->file('files');
        return $file;
```

It's been days since i'have encounter this problem, many thanks to the men who find my problem !

Comment: PHP can’t process multiple external parameters with the same name, unless you use square brackets in the parameter name. So try `formData.append("files[]", FileList[i]);`

Comment: I tried but this is not effective

Comment: Then use your browser dev tools to check what the request actually looks like, next. Compare to a “working” file upload that just uses a normal form, and no JS.